# How to get the raw type of an io-ts codec?

Tags: typescript, io-ts-library

I have an io-ts codec that is defined like this:

```
const userCodec = t.type({
  id: UUIDCodec,
  pass: passCodec
})

export type User = t.TypeOf<typeof userCodec>
```

I want to know if it's possible to derive this type to get a type like `{id: string, pass: string}` so that I don't have to define every type two times.